# How do I prevent VS Code from trying to save all unsaved files on hotkey save command and save only the current one?

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, save

I have a tendency to have multiple unsaved notes and code segments open intentionally in VS Code. I don't want to save them. This is just a holding place as I work on stuff and then I want it to go away.

Currently, when I go to save a new file I want to keep while have several others I don't want to keep, it goes through a list of all of them and tries to save them each one at a time. I don't want that. I just want to save the file in the current viewport.

The hotkey I use is Command + S (which is the default "Save" hotkey on Mac OS X). Note that in VS Code's menu, it states that the "Save All" hotkey is Option + Command + S.

Is there a way to have it ignore the other unsaved files when saving the current one?

Comment: if `Command + S` and `Option + Command + S` are bound to different commands but behave the same you first need to try the key binding debugging to see which actual command is executed and otherwise file an ssue

Answer (score 1):

To save all files and don't want VS code to ask to save completely unsaved files, you can use the below keyboard shortcut.

File.Save All Files (workbench.action.files.saveFiles)

[image]

This will only save previously saved files.